# How to store filtered data?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I'm building an API which handles purely the storage of data.

Let's imagine inside Redis I've remembered the key `foo:123` for 20 minutes, which holds an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) since I'm using the collection later on rather than returning the *raw* json.

As example the foo collection could look like

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Doe",
      "first_name":"John",
      "age":42,
      "favorite_color":"red"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Example",
      "first_name":"Eric",
      "age":37,
      "favorite_color":"black"
   },
   ....
]
```

How would I store a *new* collection, which has the same structure **but** entries having **black** as `favorite_color`? Would I have to store something like `foo:123:black`? Do I store the full collection and filter it down manually? Or is this done completely different when using Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: How would I store a new collection, which has the same structure but entries having black as favorite_color?**

Why not just map over the collection and update the favorite_color to black?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map.  Then store it however you want, either overwrite the old data or create new data.

**Q: Would I have to store something like foo:123:black?**

It's not clear to me what you're asking for here.  I'm not sure we can give you any answers on how you choose to store it or the naming convention.

**Q: Do I store the full collection and filter it down manually?**

This is something you would need to decide based on your app requirements.  It should be possible to serialize a collection and store it, but it may be a huge waste of resources if you're doing this with a bunch of different collections that have minor differences.

Comment: 1) I meant that I'm fetching all entries from the database where the favorite_color is matching *black*.

2) The question is if it's fine when something like this is stored as key => value or that's a good point to start digging into lists/hashes/sets. And if so, which one would suit the best for that use-case.

But thanks so far! :)

Comment: Yeah, a lot of this is going to be generic and opinion based because none of us will know enough about your application.    I'd say what you would need to worry about with foo:123:black is naming conflicts (could anything else have the name foo:123:black?  Is black unique enough?), other than that, it's up to you to pick a name.  Don't spend too much energy on pre-optimization, do what feels natural, then work on optimizing if it's using too much memory, cpu, time etc.